# Netbeans and Java. Import jar and use main method inside it

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, manifest

I'm new with Java, using Netbeans ide. My project should import a jar file, extends one of its classes and use the main function of another class in the same jar. So I imported jar file in Library, I created a new source package with the extended class, and it builds correctly. When I try to run, it ask me "select the main class" and I don't know how to tell him to use the one inside the jar.

Somewhere I read I should edit manifest.mf, but I'm not even sure that what am trying to do is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to run a class from NetBeans, it will try to locate a class with

```
public static void main(String[] args);
```

contract.

**It has to be defined in the project, you cannot set it from the JAR file.**